# Spring, ошибка при подключении views

Tags: java, spring, view

Помогите! Вот такая ошибка:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Небольшой контролер:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String helloView(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test", "Hello test");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Bean:

```
    @Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Application:

```
    @Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.samuliak")
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(BeanConfig.class)
public class ProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ProjectApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Скрин пути к вьюхам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.0.M21'
    compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', name: 'ecj', version: '4.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.9.5'
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Начнем с этого:  `resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/"); `   вместо  `resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");`  
и пожалуйста добавьте к листингу файл build.gradle

Comment: Сделал, пока что ничего не изменилось

Comment: thymeleaf  уберите и посмотрим на следующую ошибку)

Comment: Урааа работает!!!!) Спасибо большое!)

Comment: не за что, удачи) Если вы не против то я формлю коменты в виде ответа и закроем вопрос

Comment: без проблем!) ещё раз, благодарю за помощь!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 поставить:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

вместо:

```
resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
```

2 убрать из зависимостей

```
   compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
```